# Call an agent in our team (SIP client) and then connect them to a customer (PSTN number)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

please could anyone help with advice on how to do this using the API? I am looking to use some javascript to call our agent first on their SIP address and then start outbound calling the customer on their PSTN number from the agent.

The snippet below will achieve it, but in the wrong order as it sets up the customer call first, waits until they answer, and then calls the agent SIP client.

I want to call the agent first, wait until they answer, then call the customer.

This is a 121 call, not a conference so I don't think I can use that method because if the agent hangs up I want the call to end completely.

Many thanks!

```
client.calls
.create({     
to: '+44xxCUSTOMERNUMBERxxxxx',
from: '+44xxxCALLERIDxxxx',
twiml: '<Response><Dial><Sip>agent@domain.sip.us1.twilio.com;region=ie1</Sip></Dial></Response>'
})
```

.then(call => console.log(call.sid));

Answer (score 0):

You would refer to the SIP URI in the **To** instead of the customer phone number and your TwiML would be to the customer phone number.

From the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#call-properties) on the Call Resource:

**to**
The phone number, **SIP address**, Client identifier or SIM SID that received this call. Phone numbers are in E.164 format (e.g., +16175551212). SIP addresses are formatted as name@company.com. Client identifiers are formatted client:name. SIM SIDs are formatted as sim:sid.